# Change of Date format

Tags: r, datetime

I have a table with date and temperature, and I need to convert the date from this format `1/1/2021 12:00:00 AM` to just `1/1/21`. Please help. I tried to add a new column with the new date using this code

```r
SFtemps$Date <- as.Date(strptime(SFtemps$Date, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"))
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean in this case? Note that you seem to be converting to a Date object, but the representation you want is non the default way Dates print so you'll have to format it with `strftime()` as well.

Comment: Use “%Y” for 4 digit years in `strptime` for input, and then output with `format(SFtemps$Date, "%m/%d/%y")`.  If you just assign the mdy formatted to something else you can leave the DateTime result as is which would allow comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `%I` to represent hours as decimal number (01–12), not `%H`, and `%y` to
years without century (00–99).

```r
x <- "1/1/2021 12:00:00 AM"

format(strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), "%m/%d/%y")
[1] "01/01/21"
```

Note that after you re-foramt the time object, it'll be a pure character string and lose all attributes of a time object.

Answer (score 2):

Your string is actually a timestamp, using `lubridate` you can convert it to the desired format and then leverage `stamp` function to get your data formatted in the manner that suits you.

```r
org_str <- "1/1/2021 12:00:00 AM"
library("lubridate")
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
x <- mdy_hms(x = org_str, tz = "UTC")
sf <- stamp("29/01/1997")
#> Multiple formats matched: "%d/%Om/%Y"(1), "%d/%m/%Y"(1)
#> Using: "%d/%Om/%Y"
sf(x)
#> [1] "01/01/2021"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

## Explanation

Contrary to common perception the date doesn't have a format as such. Only string representation of the date can be of a specific format. Consider the following example. Running code:

```r
x <- Sys.Date()
unclass(x)
```

will return an integer. This is because<sup>1</sup>:

> Thus, objects of the class Date are internally represented as numbers. More specifically, dates in R are actually integers.

The same is applicable to the POSIX objects

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
xn <- now()
class(xn)
#> [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
unclass(xn)
#> [1] 1650644616
#> attr(,"tzone")
#> [1] ""
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You can always run:

```r
format.Date(lubridate::now(), "%d-%m")
# [1] "22-04"
```

However, by doing this you *are not formatting the date* but creating a *string representation* of the date / timestamp object. Your string representation would have to be converted to timestamp / date object if you want to use it in common date time operations.

## Suggestions

Whenever working with date time / date objects I would argue that it's advisable to keep those objects as a correct class maintaining the relevant details (such as time zone in case of timestamps) and only leverage formatting functions when utilising the data in analysis / visual representation, as shown in the sample.

---

<sup>1</sup> [Essentials of dates and times](https://bookdown.org/hneth/ds4psy/10-2-time-essentials.html)

Comment: You only provided an answer to the first error but then did not provide a correct format string for the second issue.

Comment: @IRTFM I've expanded on my answer. In my view, if the OP's intention is to format the timestamp, say for the purpose of generating presentable summary, the formatting functions should be applied as a last step prior to report delivery. I find that OP should steer away from storing a string column `"1/1/21"` reflecting a date. I would advise OP to bring original strings to a suitable class say POSIXct and only format the date at a final stage. But I agree that this is an opinionated answer and other colleagues may prefer to actually store a column as a string, which is achievable via the `sf`.

Comment: I do share your opinion and everything you state appears correct to me. However I only upvoted the answer that actually did what was requested.

Comment: @IRTFM Of course, makes sense. Good discussion to have.

Answer (score 1):

Your format is a bit off. These are two options that work (lubridate is my favorite):

```
SFtemps <- list()
SFtemps$Date <- '1/1/2021 12:00:00 AM'


> as.Date(strptime(SFtemps$Date, "%m/%d/%Y %r"))
[1] "2021-01-01"
> as.Date(lubridate::mdy_hms(SFtemps$Date))
[1] "2021-01-01"
```

This will give you the date. If you want to see it as 1/1/2021, use the `format` function

Answer (score -1):

You can try [tryFormats](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/as.Date)

```
as.Date(x, format, tryFormats = c("%m/%d/%y, %H:%M"),
optional = FALSE)
```

Comment: You’re committing the same error as the OP.